# prepend text to every n:th line in a textfile

Tags: sed, bioinformatics

This sed comandline script prepends text on every line in a file:

```
sed -i 's/^/to be prepended/g' text.txt
```

How can I make it so it only do that on every n<sup>th</sup>  line?

I am working with sequencing data and in the "norma" multiple fasta format there is first an identifier line staring with a > and then have additional text.

The next line starts with a random DNA sequence like "AATTGCC" and so on when that string is done its new line and new identifier, how can i prepend text (additional bases) to the beginning of the sequence line?

Comment: Fasta format is not always alternate header/sequence lines, you should not rely on that! Just use the fact that only header lines starts with '>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ seq 10 | perl -pe's/^/to be prepended / unless $. % 3'
1
2
to be prepended 3
4
5
to be prepended 6
7
8
to be prepended 9
10
$ seq 10 | perl -pe's/^/to be prepended / unless $. % 3 - 1'
to be prepended 1
2
3
to be prepended 4
5
6
to be prepended 7
8
9
to be prepended 10
$ seq 10 | perl -pe's/^/to be prepended / unless $. % 3 - 2'
1
to be prepended 2
3
4
to be prepended 5
6
7
to be prepended 8
9
10
```

You have an idea.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the following GNU `sed` syntax:

```
sed '0~Ns/^/to be prepended/'
#    ^^^
#    set N to the number you want!
```

for example, prepend HA to lines numbers that are multiple of 4:

```
$ seq 10 | sed '0~4s/^/HA/'
1
2
3
HA4
5
6
7
HA8
9
10
```

Or to those that are on the form `4N+1`:

```
$ seq 10 | sed '1~4s/^/HA/'
HA1
2
3
4
HA5
6
7
8
HA9
10
```

From the [`sed` manual → 3.2. Selecting lines with `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses):

> **first~step**
>
> This GNU extension matches every stepth line starting with line first. In particular, lines will be selected when there exists a non-negative n such that the current line-number equals first + (n * step). Thus, to select the odd-numbered lines, one would use 1~2; to pick every third line starting with the second, ‘2~3’ would be used; to pick every fifth line starting with the tenth, use ‘10~5’; and ‘50~0’ is just an obscure way of saying 50.

By the way, there is no need to use `/g` for global replacement, since `^` can just be replaced once on every line.

Answer (score 0):

```
seq 15|awk -v line=4  'NR%line==0{$0="Prepend this text : " $0}1'
1
2
3
Prepend this text : 4
5
6
7
Prepend this text : 8
9
10
11
Prepend this text : 12
13
14
15
```